# Getting an error when trying to compare the result of a function to a boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to create a simple code to calculate all perfect numbers (as far as my laptop would allow) but when i tried to compare the result of the function I made to a Boolean it's giving me an error.

This my function to check if a number is prime:

```
def prime(Num):
    while True:
        Testnum=2
        while Num>=Testnum:
            if Num%Testnum!=0 and Num>Testnum:
                Testnum+=1
            elif Num%Testnum==0 and Num==Testnum:
                a=True
                return a
            elif x%y==0 and x>y:
                a=False
                return a
```

The code to compare and then calculate the perfect number:

```
import prime
x=2
y=2**x-1
while True:
    if prime(y) is True:
        print((2**x-1)*(2**(num-1)))
    x=x+1
    y=2**x-1
```

And the error I'm receiving when I try to run the code:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\abhik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\perfectnum.py",
> line 5, in <module>
>     if prime(y) is True: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Do you have the function in the same python file as the main code? Or do you have it in a separate file, e.g., `prime.py`?

Comment: You need to do `from prime import prime`  since you are importing the prime function from the prime.py file. Whoever closed the question did it for the wrong reason (there are no typos in the code). The question is valid and by closing it, it prevents the OP from getting useful answers, which have to be provided in the comments.

Comment: `import prime` means `prime` is a module. If you want to call the function `prime` within module `prime`, you need `prime.prime(y)`.

Comment: Also note that `is True` is superfluous; just `if prime.prime(y):` will do just fine.

Comment: @deceze this ***isn't*** a typo issue

Comment: @Elerium115 Questions should at least be signposts for future visitors. No future visitor is going to find this solution with the question as posed, because this has nothing to do with booleans. The question should focus on the actual error message, not wrong speculations. _If_ this question got fixed to point to the actual problem, I'm sure we can close it as duplicate of a dozen other questions. … Or we just close it as "you're trying to call something by the wrong name "typo"".

Comment: @deceze By that logic any syntax error is a typo. Care to link any documentation stating syntax errors get closed as typos?

Comment: @MatBailie Why yes, syntax *mistakes* __are__ closed as typos. That's what the option is for. There's of course a fine line and some discretion when something is a useful question about syntax and when something is just some fat-fingered code, but in general "I typed the wrong thing and that's why my code doesn't work" questions aren't useful to anyone else in the future, and thus get cleaned up. There's a bunch of discussion about that to be found on Meta of course, e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/476.